# List: remove line delimiter

Tags: list, json-formatting, view-formatting

Is it possible to remove the light greyish delimiters in a SharePoint List?
[image]

I already set margin to 0 but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing `hideSelection` property in JSON code to:

```
"hideSelection": true
```